# How to make auto-genertion(auto-fill and increment) in django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to make code field should be auto filled and auto increment in django admin.
models.py

```
class GeneralDocumentType(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to show my code field default=DOC001, and it will show increment by 1 before adding data by user.How can I achieve this?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django `ModelAdmin` has support for [get_changeform_initial_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data). In your admin you can override this method to get value based on the latest id info. For example:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  ...
  def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    # getting the latest id
    try:
        latest_document_type = GeneralDocumentType.object.latest('id')
        latest_id = latest_document_type.id + 1
    except GeneralDocumentType.DoesNotExist:
        # incase there no object yet
        latest_id = 0
        
    return {'code': f'DOC{latest_id}'}
```

Note: this only work for `adding` new object, `ModelAdmin`. Doesn't work for `InlineModelAdmin`

Comment: Its working but i want to give 3digit format how can i set that??

Comment: @VijiLakshmi maybe you can make another question for that in the python section, i only helped with the part related to django :)